# Using tc to delay packets to all IP address except for a single IP address

Tags: linux, centos, tc

I'm familiar with this post here:
[Using tc to delay packets to only a single IP address](https://serverfault.com/questions/389290/using-tc-to-delay-packets-to-only-a-single-ip-address)

Which will delay outbound packets to a single IP address. I want to do the opposite, which is to delay all outbound packets except for a single ip address. Is this doable using tc? I've been going through documentation (https://omf.mytestbed.net/projects/omf/wiki/NetEM_examples_of_rules) and tutorials without any progress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `fw` match instead of `u32` match then you can use iptables rules with `MARK` target to invert the condition (`! -d X.X.X.X -j MARK --set-mark i`).